# using core-pages, is there a page-loaded event?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, polymer

In a `core-(animated)-pages` collection, I need my selected page to react on the fact that it became the selected one. I cannot figure out what event to catch where. Tried a simple `load` but that does not get called.

If there is no such event by default, can the `on-core-select` somehow trigger an event in the `my-element` to let it know it should load it's data?

```
            <core-animated-pages id="appPages" selected="{{selectedPage}}" valueattr="data-name" transitions="slide-from-right" on-core-select="{{pageSelected}}">
                <my-page data-name="Round 1" color="red">
                    <div>Page 1</div>
                </my-page>
                <my-page data-name="Round 2" color="yellow">
                    <div>Page 2</div>
                </my-page>
                <my-page data-name="Round 3" color="grey">
                    <div>Page 3</div>
                </my-page>
            </core-animated-pages>



<polymer-element name="my-page" attributes="color">
<template>
    <section data-name="Round 1" layout vertical center center-justified style="background:{{color}};">
        <content></content>
    </section>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer('my-page', {
        load: function (e) {
            console.info(e)
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: the way am doing something close to what you are talking about is using flatiron-director and making each page in my core-animated-pages a route and listening for the route to change and do then  do my function.

Comment: Thanks, guess I'm doing something similar now, see comment on the next answer

Comment: great glad you got it to work. only difference in the functionality i know of in the 2 approaches is with flatiron-director you get routed pages.. ie. www.url.com#page1. should have just posted my code but i wan't 100% sure that was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the core-animated-pages docs (https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-animated-pages), the element takes your transitions name and looks for elements containing the same word. For example:

```
<core-animated-pages transitions="hero-transition">
   <section id="page1">
     <div id="hero1" hero-id="hero" hero></div>
   </section>
   <section id="page2">
      <div id="hero2" hero-id="hero" hero></div>
  </section>
</core-animated-pages>
```

This should help you avoid writing logic to show/hide your element.
The docs also display events triggered before and after the transition occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are two events that are fired at different times:

- `core-animated-pages-transition-prepare` and
- `core-animated-pages-transition-end` .

From https://github.com/Polymer/core-animated-pages :

```
<!--
  Fired before a page transition occurs. Both pages involved in the transition are visible when
  this event fires. This is useful if there is something the client needs to do when a page becomes visible.

  @event core-animated-pages-transition-prepare
-->

<!--
  Fired when a page transition completes.

  @event core-animated-pages-transition-end
-->
```

Comment: That is interesting but does not seem to help in my case. The two event handlers don't seem go have any information about the pages it's dealing with. Dead End.

I went back to examine the `on-core-selected` and indeed, the `detail.item` can be used to get to the stuff within the page, especially the `core-ajax` element and I can then trigger a `go()` on that to fetch fresh data.

thanks for making me rethink :-)